# UIButton in PopoverView with own XIB should send action to mainview

Tags: xcode, ipad, uibutton, uipopovercontroller, first-responder

I have a popover view which is called with:

```
Info *infoview = [[Info alloc]init];
pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:infoview];
[pop setDelegate:self];
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(-60, 30, 400, 400) inView:bigMenuView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
[infoview release];
```

In this popoverview is (see in the code) an info.xib which has some UIBUttons.

Now I want to change something. in my "mainview" after I click on the Button.

Note: I can access my IBAction Method in the "First Responder" but the is no action.

Comment: so you want the button in `infoview` to send a message to the `mainView` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you want, declare a property on the button in `Info`, something like :

```
@property(retain) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

Now synthesize it, in implementation part. In order for the button to send the correct action to the correct target, you should do like :

```
Info *infoview = [[Info alloc]init];
// set the action/target here
[infoView.myButton addTarget:bigMenuView
                      action:@selector(theSELYouWant)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:infoview];
[pop setDelegate:self];
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(-60, 30, 400, 400)
                     inView:bigMenuView
   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
[infoview release];
```

I supposed that the main view is `bigMenuView`.
This will make the button sending a `theSELYouWant` message to `bigMenuView` each time it is touched.

Comment: ok thanks! the @selector command sends Actions wherever i want? the second code snip takes part in my info.m? EDIT: the second part takes part in my mainView... i guess...

Comment: `@selector` will actually return a `SEL`, which is the type that represent [selectors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html).Yes, you should write a method `-(void)theSELYouWant;` in the target you specified, in you case the main view. give it a try, and if my answer fits your needs, click the checkmark ;)

Comment: ok... my mainview is not bigmenuView, that is just a view to show a menu in the MainView... the selectorYouWant is (button_click:) it is ab IBAction method in my mainview, but nothing happened :-/

Comment: can i select my target there with "self"?

Comment: `[infoView.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: ok makes sense... but i doesnt work. Again: i have MainView, in this view i have another view (BigMenuView) in this BigmenuView is a Button which opens an UIPopOverController with another View (InfoView) where some UIbuttons are. :-) These UIButtons are via IB connected with your MyButton and the with button_click: method over First Responder in the MainView. In the MainView i have implemented the second part of your code (target: self, action: button_click:)

Comment: so `MainView` is the superview for `BigMenuView`, but `InfoView` is a 'UIView' subclass of your own ? so the code snippet you wrote takes place in `MainView`, which is `self`. Just to be sure could you log `infoView.myButton` using `NSLog(@"%@", infoView.myButton);` just after alloc/init `infoView` ? of course replace `myButton` by the property name.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", infoView);` too if you can, some of those may be nil

Comment: Ok great hint! I took the @selector after that: pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:infoview];
 and now it works perfectly!!! thank you Vince!

Comment: you are welcome Phil, another way is specifying `nil` as the target, which may send the action message up the responder chain